# Dice throwing; no throw > 6

Tags: probability

Im stuck at this question

a) Let k be a fixed number, such that 1 ≤ k ≤ 6. Suppose that the die is thrown n times, with throws assumed to be independent. Show that the probability of the event

{no throw resulted in a number > than k}

is given by

(k/6)^n

(b) Now assume that the die is thrown a random number N times, where N can take
two values, 5 and 10, with probabilities 1/3 and 2/3, respectively (throws are independent). What is the probability of the event {no throw resulted in a number > than k}
in that case?

Comment: What specifically are you stuck with here?  Recall, "no throw greater than k" is equivalent to "every throw less than or equal to k."  If you throw once, what is the chance the throw is less than or equal to $k$?  If you throw twice, what is the chance the first throw is less than or equal to $k$?  What is the chance the second is?  What is the chance that both are?  Recall the definition of independent events.  Extend to $n$ throws.

Comment: As for the second part... recall your law of total probability.  $\Pr(A)=\Pr(A\mid B)\Pr(B)+\Pr(A\mid B^c)\Pr(B^c)$, here letting $A$ be the event no throw exceeded $k$ and $B$ the event that it was the case that we threw the die $5$ times as opposed to $10$.

Comment: I think i was expecting it to be a lot more difficult, so i didn't see the clear answer for a).